# Cannot add token to outgoing request using Strawberry Shake Graph QL client

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-webassembly, .net-8.0, hotchocolate, strawberryshake

My Blazor .NET 8 WASM app uses the StrawberryShake GraphQL client to connect to a HotChocolate GraphQL endpoint in an ASP NET Web API project. I am following the [official docs](https://chillicream.com/docs/strawberryshake/v13/networking/authentication) but I'm having trouble injecting the access token into the request.

Here's what I have tried: `AddGqlClient()` is a method generated by StrawberryShake:

```cs
builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(...);
builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore(...);

builder.Services.AddGqlClient()
                .ConfigureHttpClient(async (sp, client) => 
                {
                    var provider = sp.GetRequiredService<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.IAccessTokenProvider>();
                    var tokenResult = await provider.RequestAccessToken();
                    tokenResult.TryGetToken(out AccessToken? jwt);
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri($"{apiUrl}/graphql");
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", jwt.Value);
                });
```

The builds okay, but when I make a request, I get an error

> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve scoped service 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.IAccessTokenProvider' from root provider

Can someone share some insights on what I can improve? Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As so often, after asking here the solution was found. Posting here so it might be helpful for someone. The key was to use the factory approach as outlined [here](https://chillicream.com/docs/strawberryshake/v12/networking/authentication#httpclientfactory).

```cs
builder.Services.AddHttpClient(GqlClient.ClientName, client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri($"{apiUrl}/graphql"))
                .AddHttpMessageHandler<ApiAuthzRequestMessageHandler>();
builder.Services.AddGqlClient();
```

The httpclient name `GqlClient.ClientName` was also generated by StrawberryShake so there is a match.